# Cant get Excel to format my dates correctly

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

In Excel I have a column formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD` with the Locale of **English (Australia)**, I am entering the data in the US format however (US Locale didn't provide the `YYYY-MM-DD` option).

So I'm trying to paste in dates in the format `M/D/YY`, so no leading zeroes on MONTH or DAY and only 2 chars on YEAR.

Is there anyway this can be converted to the `YYYY-MM-DD` format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for Excel to properly parse a date that you enter, it must be

- entered in the same format as the `Short Date` format in your **Windows Regional Settings** (nothing to do in Excel to change this)
- OR entered in an unambiguous fashion:  eg: 2017-09-23; 23 Sep 2017; etc

The format of the cell has **nothing** to do with how Excel interprets the entry.  It only affects how a numeric entry within the cell is displayed.

Once Excel has parsed the date and converted it into a number (representing days and fractions of a day since `1-Jan-1900`), then it will reformat according to whatever format you have set.

If the above two options are not possible, and you cannot change your **Windows Regional Short Date** settings, another option is to enter the date as text, and then run the `Text-to-Columns` wizard wherein you can specify the DMY order.  If the data is coming from a `CSV` file, you can `Import` instead of `Opening` the file to bring up the same wizard.

It is possible to use formulas, but you have to then differentiate between a date that is still in text format vs one that has been converted incorrectly to an "Excel" date.

Which method is best depends on exactly what you are doing; whether it is a one time entry; whether the data is coming from CSV or someplace else, etc.

Comment: Ahhh... that makes total sense now that I know that the _format_ has nothing to do with the way Excel interprets it. Cheers!

Comment: @Brett That is a pretty common misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using Excel's [custom date](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8E10019E-D5D8-47A1-BA95-DB95123D273E#__toc320186183) function. The instructions can be found at that link, but basically this is what you would do:

- Right click on a cell that's formatted as `Date` and select **Format Cells...**
- Select **Custom** under the *Number* tab
- In the input field under *Type:* enter `yyyy/mm/dd`
- Click **OK**

Now, when you paste (or type) a date that's in a different format, Excel will convert it to your format -- as long as you don't copy the source formatting.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work :(

Comment: @Brett What happens when you try it? Are you copying and pasting a **cell**, or the **value** of a cell?

Comment: I'm copying a date from outside of Excel and then pasting it into Excel, however when I paste it the value does not change, it stays exactly as entered.

Comment: Are you right-clicking on the cell and pasting, or pasting it into the formula bar?

Comment: Right-clicking.

Comment: You have to paste it into the formula bar directly; otherwise it overwrites the cell's existing formatting. Click on the cell to select it, then right click on the formula bar and paste the date there and it will keep the existing formatting.

Comment: Afraid that didn't make any difference.

Comment: So to clarify: you set up the date formatting how you want it, copy the date from outside Excel, select a cell in Excel, right click on the formula bar, select Paste, and hit <ENTER>, and it still changes the formatting away from YYYY/MM/DD?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing. However, it doesn't change the formatting of the cell, it just doesn't display the data in the correct format of the cell.

Comment: That's strange. What program are you copying the date from?

Comment: Just a webpage; but even if I type it into the formula bar manually and hit enter it doesn't work either.

Comment: If you right click on the cell (before you paste to it) and select **Format Cell** does it show the date format correctly? (`yyyy/mm/dd`)

Comment: Yes and that is the way it stays after pasting into it as well.

Comment: Try this format as the type instead: `yyyy/mm/dd;@`. Does that make any difference?

Comment: No change, however I did notice if I enter in `29/5/98` it works, but `5/29/98` doesn't; so it doesn't seem to understand the US format.

Comment: That's weird. You could try basing it off of a US-style date to see if that makes a difference. For example, select a date type like `m/dd/yy` and set that on the cell, then go in and customize the format from there and see if that works any differently.

Comment: No good on that I'm afraid.